Spark 3.5.1 is not reading s3 object content
I am trying to read an s3 object from a local S3 storage (Ceph based) using Spark 3.5.1.
I see it can access the bucket and list the files, even returning the correct size of the object. But the content is not read. Here is my Pyspark code:
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAll([
    ("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.6"),
    ("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "R*************6"),
    ("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "1***************e"),
    ("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "192.168.52.63:8000")
])


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .config(conf=conf) \
    .appName("read-s3-with-spark") \
    .getOrCreate()

schema = StructType(
   [StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('int1', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('int2', IntegerType(), True)
   ]
  )

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")

df = spark.read \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .csv("s3a://input/testfile.csv", sep=' ')

df.show(n=1)

I see this debug message too:
DEBUG S3AFileSystem: s3a://input/testfile.csv: testfile.csv size=18
But the return INFO log shows this:
24/05/20 02:35:00 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system started
24/05/20 02:35:01 INFO MetadataLogFileIndex: Reading streaming file log from s3a://input/testfile.csv/_spark_metadata
24/05/20 02:35:01 INFO FileStreamSinkLog: BatchIds found from listing:
24/05/20 02:35:03 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Pushed Filters:
24/05/20 02:35:03 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Post-Scan Filters:
24/05/20 02:35:03 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 176.139675 ms
24/05/20 02:35:03 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 496.6 KiB, free 4.1 GiB)
24/05/20 02:35:03 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 54.4 KiB, free 4.1 GiB)
24/05/20 02:35:03 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on master:38197 (size: 54.4 KiB, free: 4.1 GiB)
24/05/20 02:35:03 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0
24/05/20 02:35:03 INFO FileSourceScanExec: Planning scan with bin packing, max size: 4194304 bytes, open cost is considered as scanning 4194304 bytes.
+----+----+----+
|name|int1|int2|
+----+----+----+
+----+----+----+

24/05/20 02:35:04 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
24/05/20 02:35:04 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0

testfile.csv content is this:
name int1 int2
first 1 2
second 3 4

Has anyone any idea what is wrong?

can you directly list from the s3 whether data is present there. What i can see is there is data present in _spark_metadata which spark ignores.

as per this log  -
24/05/20 02:35:01 INFO MetadataLogFileIndex: Reading streaming file log from s3a://input/testfile.csv/_spark_metadata
testfile.csv is a directory not a file

@AyushGoyal yes, using hdfs and s3cmd I can see the objects:
2024-05-20 01:17        18   s3://input/testfile.csv
Spark treating the object as a bucket is one of the things that confuses me. It shouldn't happen.

root paths are special, try with a path underneath. (you can't delete them, there is no parent directory, ...)

@Aminmosayyebzadeh try stevel suggestion and also add ("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true") property and check if its working.

I dont know how spark interpreting _spark_metadata directory in s3 for you. It is generally created in Spark structure streaming to track the number of files outputted.

and if possible use spark committer for s3.
https://spark.apache.org/committers.html

@stevel I changed the bucket from s3://input/ to s3://test1/test2/test2/ and result is still the same.

@AyushGoyal I checked the logs more and I see the variable OP_IS_DIRECTORY gets set to 1. But I don't see OP_IS_FILE gets set.
